# Port forward not working to set a local web server

Tags: node.js, webserver, portforwarding

I have just created a simple web server using node server and it's running fine. I can access it from the same PC by going to address `http://127.0.0.1:1337`.

Now I want to access that web server from my WAN IP. I got my my using whatismyip and got something like `110.36.xxx.xxx`.

When I tried `http://110.36.xxx.xxx:1337`, I got:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 110.36.xxx.xxx:1337.
```

Here is the screenshot how I created the port forwarding in my router:

[image]

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Localhost is only accessible from the same pc. You have to launch your webserver either on address 0.0.0.0 (it will be available on all network interfaces) or 192.186.0.5 so that it is accessible from your wan interface

Comment: I have installed the server on 198.168.0.5 but now its working from the same LAN but not outside the LAN i.e. from 110.36.xxx.xxx:1337

Comment: You must have an "white IP" for this to work.
I guess 110.36.x.x is your provider's external IP, not yours.
Ask your ISP if they could give you external IP (and it will cost you some money).

And even if it's actually yours IP, provider still could forbid incoming connections to unusual ports.